# oracle 8i question

Tags: oracle8i

I reformat the data here. Basically, I tried to output the data from table1 into table2 but not sure how to write it in oracle 8i. I am running Aqua Studio but the database backend is oracle.

Thanks alot!!!

```
Table1: 
Name   Prods   Cus_id 
-----------------------
Mark   Rice    87311870 
Judy   Rice    87364239 
-----------------------
Tom    Coffee  87404026 
Tom    Apple   87404026 
Tom    Milk    87404026 
Tom    Source  87404026 
-----------------------
Hunt   Chips   87570092
-----------------------
```

Table2:

```
Name        Prod1   Prod2   Prod3   Prod4   Cus_id 
-----------------------------------------------------
Mark        Rice                            87311870
-----------------------------------------------------
Judy        Rice                            87364239 
-----------------------------------------------------
Tom         Coffee  Apple   Milk    Source  87404026
-----------------------------------------------------
Hunt        Chips                           87570092
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How do i format this property, though?

Comment: code blocks can be made by starting each line with at least four spaces (and replacing tabs with spaces) - I've fixed it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to transfer data from one table to another, use the `insert..select` command:

```
insert into table2 (col1, col2) select col1, col2 from table1;
```

Beyond that, it's just a matter of morphing the data to the desired format. SO has a plethora of questions on [turning rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+rows+columns).

In my *opinion*, this is usually a bad idea. I'm all for presenting data like this since your users may desire it but that's something that should be done in the presentation layer, not in the database.

Creating a table of this style (non third normal form) is usually enough for our DBAs to either reject the change outright or, at a minimum, bring you in for a stern taking to, which may include some ridicule and questioning of your parentage depending on how much sleep they had the night before :-)